# Angular 4 component binding doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to create a global component to be used in an Angular application, which basically should just get an array of objects that comes from a database and display its content in the html.
However, the html never loads. Angular thinks the model is null. If i do console.log on it i can see it has the right properties though, so it's clearly not null.

I thought it might be because i'm fetching the data from a database, therefore when it firstly loads its null and it doesn't update when the data arrives.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

Global Events Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ag-events',
    templateUrl: './Event.html',
    styles: [require('./Event.scss').toString()]})

export class EventListComponent {
    // Default values
    @Input() public model: EventList = <EventList>{};
}
```

Custom Page Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'planner-team-events',
    templateUrl: './TeamEvents.html',
    styleUrls: ['./TeamEvents.scss']
})
export class TeamEventsComponent implements OnInit {
    public model: EventList = <EventList>{};

    constructor(private net: NetworkService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {          
        this.net.get<EventList>(`Event/GetPlannerEvents/`).subscribe(t => {

            // Here i populate the model from Database
            this.model = t;

            console.log(this.model);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Usage (Global EventComponent)

```
<div class="event-wrapper"  *ngFor="let model of model.eventList">
    <div class="event">
        <div class="event-image">
            <img src={{model.eventImage.link}} />
            <div class="banner">
                <h5>{{model.event.name}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML Usage (Under TeamEvents.html)

```
 <ag-events [model]="model"></ag-events>
```

Lastly, my model:

```
export interface EventList {
    eventList:EventViewModel[];
}

export interface EventViewModel {
    event: Event;
    eventImage: AngularImage;
    category: EventCategory;
    type:EventType;
    color: Color;

    campus: Organization;
    campusImage: AngularImage;
    juniorOrg: Organization;
    juniorOrgImage: AngularImage;
}
```

As required, the database json response:

```
{
 "events": [
  {
   "event": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Legal",
    "description": "Dwqdwqdwqd",
    "imageId": 20,
    "categoryId": 3,
    "typeId": 3,
    "universityId": 1,
    "campusId": 3,
    "juniorOrgId": 7,
    "price": 0,
    "pinned": false,
    "link": null,
    "startDate": "2018-07-18T10:45:00",
    "endDate": "2018-08-21T16:40:00",
    "approvedOn": null,
    "approvedBy": null,
   },
   "eventImage": {
    "link": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/",
    "base64String": null,
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
   },
   "campus": {
    "id": 3,
    "organizationTypeId": 2,
    "name": "FT",
    "abbreviation": "AC",
    "description": null,
    "imageId": 14,
    "addressId": null,
    "identifier": null,
    "approvedOn": null,
    "approvedBy": null,
    "contactId": null,
    "parentId": 1,
    "children": null
   },
   "campusImage": {
    "link": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "base64String": null,
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
   },
   "juniorOrg": {
    "id": 7,
    "organizationTypeId": 3,
    "name": "MTE",
    "abbreviation": "JCA",
    "description": null,
    "imageId": 14,
    "addressId": null,
    "identifier": null,
    "approvedOn": null,
    "approvedBy": null,
    "contactId": null,
    "parentId": 3,,
    "children": null
   },
   "juniorOrgImage": {
    "link": "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/",
    "base64String": null,
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
   },
   "category": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Engenharia",
    "colorId": 1,
   },
   "categoryColor": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Black",
    "hex": "#000000",
    "rgb": "rgb(0,0,0)"
   },
   "type": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Workshop"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: can u add the logged properties came from the DB?

Comment: @RaedKhalaf There are more events, but as you can see each event has a lot of properties. I decided to delete the others and leave one so its easier to read.

Comment: Oh damn, "events" is the problem isnt it? It should be eventsList? Or maybe i can change my EventList interface to have a property called events.

Comment: It was that ^ thanks

Comment: lol, i was writing this as an answer :)

Comment: Should I delete this since it was a typo issue?